# Unchecked cast and generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class:

```
public class SomeClass <TView extends View>{

    private TView tv;

    public SomeClass(View v){
        tv=(TView) v; //unchecked cast warning
    }

}
```

`View` is a concrete class (not abstract, not interface).

**Question is**

Why do I get an unchecked cast warning, even if `TView` extends `View`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast is not enforced at runtime.

Your class post-[erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) looks like:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private View tv;  // Post-erasure, TView -> View

    public SomeClass(View v){  // Post-erasure, TView -> View
        tv=(View) v; //unchecked cast warning due to cast of View to View
    }

}
```

Note that post-erasure, the constructor is casting a value of type `View` to type `View` since that is the lower-bound for `<TView extends View>`.

Casting `View` to `View` does not check anything at runtime, which is why you get the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, but `View` does not extend `TView` which means that an instance of `View` might not be an instance of `TView`.

Imagine `View`, and `ViewA extends View` and `ViewB extends View`

If you create a `SomeClass<ViewA>` and call `new SomeClass<ViewA>((View)new ViewB())` you could cause some issues. For example, the below test will throw a `ClassCastException` at the line `ViewA oa = o.getT();`

```
class View{}

class ViewA{}

class ViewB{}

class Other<T extends View>{
    T t;

    Other(View view){
       t= (T)view;
    }

    T getT(){
       return T;
    }
}


@Test
public void testIt(){
   ViewA a = new ViewA();
   ViewB b = new ViewB();
   Other<ViewA> o = new Other<ViewA>((View)b);
   ViewA oa = o.getT();
}
```

The above compile put will fail due to the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Learn something new every day.